# Not class selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a simple selector expression to not select elements with a specific class?

```
<div class="first-foo" />
<div class="first-moo" />
<div class="first-koo" />
<div class="first-bar second-foo" />
```

I just want to get the first three divs and tried

```
$(div[class^="first-"][class!="first-bar"])
```

But this receives all as the last div contains more than first-bar. Is there a way to use a placeholder in such an expression? Something like that

```
$(div[class^="first-"][class!="first-bar*"]) // doesn't seem to work
```

Any other selectors that may help?

Comment: Scratch my earlier comment, I just reread the question. Critical class is `first-bar`.

Comment: In case one wants to select all elements that do not have either class1 or class2, concatenating would work: `$('div[class^="first-"]').not('.class1').not('.class2')`

Answer (score 659, accepted):

You need the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$('div[class^="first-"]:not(.first-bar)')
```

or, alternatively, the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
$('div[class^="first-"]').not('.first-bar');
```

Comment: Note that since :not() is up to 2-3 times faster than .not() (http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not), you might want to use :not().  However, the jQuery docs recommend using .not() instead, as it is more readable (http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).  Hope this helps someone make a decision between the two!

Comment: @rinogo It is quicker now that the vast majority of browsers support querySelectorAll, but that hasn't always been the case.

Comment: Yup, exactly! :)  I hope my comment didn't come across as criticism; I rather intended to add to your already helpful question.

Comment: Thanks!!
disable enter key on all but my Filtering Boxes.
$("input:not(.rgFilterBox)").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

Comment: How to achieve this with pure javascript.?

Comment: @rinogo, unless this function runs hundreds of times in a loop, the user will never notice the performance difference.

Comment: @Daniel, yes, but if it *is*, then it's a super easy change to get an instant performance boost :)

Comment: Thanks for showing both the `not` _selector_ and the `not` _method_.

Answer (score 111):

You can use the `:not` filter selector:

```
$('foo:not(".someClass")')
```

Or `not()` method:

```
$('foo').not(".someClass")
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: The `"` should be omitted if using it as a CSS selector.

Comment: @BoltClock: It is needed for values with spaces in them, i have made it a habit of mine to specify those always :)

Answer (score 5):

You can write a jQuery selector in the "not" method:

`$('div[class^="first-"]').not($('.first-bar'))`

Comment: this exact answer is already answered by @lonesomeday ! what do you have to add ?

Comment: first, my answer is different. Secondly, I had such a case was, I needed to exclude a class that was a child. To do this, I was helped by the jQuery selector in the "not" method. I just wrote not ($('. first-bar'). parent ()). I think that my version will help someone.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!, now it may help someone!

Answer (score 2):

It also works on jQuery events with `:not()` selector.

Simply like this :

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.fo-line:not(.deleted) .clickable', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do your stuff...
});
```

*In my case, I enable click on every `<td class="clickable">` of `<tr class="fo-line">` expected all with `deleted` class (`<tr class="fo-line deleted">`)*