# Select a button element without certain classes

Tags: jquery, html, class

I have a button in my webpage. This button I want to have the class "btn-default", but I prefer not to write that out each time. How can I use jQuery to give every button that doesn't have the classes: "btn-warning btn-primary btn-danger" the "btn-default" class?

Comment: I cant understood your question. could you tell clearly?

Comment: Basically. I want to use jQuery to target buttons that don't have classes A, B, or C. How do I do this?

Comment: I think you want select the button which button has not classes A,B,C. Is it correct?

Comment: So are you saying; (only buttons that do not have a class of X) on click do something? It's not clear...

Comment: Take a look at the `.not()` selector: (http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614120/not-class-selector-in-jquery

Comment: I understand the `.not()` selector now, but I how I put multiple arguments into the `.not()` selector?

Comment: For completeness regarding the usage of `.not()`, you can use something like `$('button').not('.classA, .classB, .classC').addClass('btn-default');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## jQuery Selectors

The :not() selector is a wonderful tool inside of jQuery!

```
$('button:not(.btn-primary, .btn-warning, .btn-danger)').addClass('btn-default');
```

Using the .not() function

```
$('button').not('.btn-primary, .btn-warning, .btn-danger').addClass('btn-default').css('background-color', 'blue');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ow0ez3xd/

---

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to catch each button on the page using

```
$( ":button" )
```

then check if it has a specific class using:

```
$( ":button" ).hasClass( "foo" )
```

if not u can add ur own class

```
$( ":button" ).addClass( "foo" )
```