# jQuery select children only if container NOT have certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to attach hover function to children of div, BUT only if this div don't have certain class. To illustrate my intent - i want hover function to be triggered upon mouse entering any ".hover-button" element, UNLESS container ".column" has class ".disabled" added to it:

```js
 $('.hover-button').hover( function() { 
   //showing tooltip
 } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="hover-button"></div>
  <div class="hover-button"></div>
  <div class="hover-button"></div>
</div>

<div class="column disabled">
  <div class="hover-button"></div>
  <div class="hover-button"></div>
  <div class="hover-button"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614120/not-class-selector-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `:not` selector. Take a look at this code, particularly this snippet

`.column:not(.disabled) > .hover-button`

```js
$('.column:not(.disabled) > .hover-button').on("mouseover", function() { 
    $(this).css({"background": "gold"}); 
 }).on("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).css({"background": "white"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="hover-button">Hover Here</div>
  <div class="hover-button">And Here</div>
  <div class="hover-button">And Here</div>
</div>

<div class="column disabled">
  <div class="hover-button">But not here</div>
  <div class="hover-button">Or here</div>
  <div class="hover-button">Or here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Marked your answer as the best one, because of simplicity and also for included example.

Comment: I'm happy to have helped you

Answer (score 1):

Use the Not Method

```
 $('.column:not(.disabled)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not()` in a selector to exclude elements that match another selector.

But if the class will change dynamically, you need to use delegation binding, not normal event binding.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        // show tooltip
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        // remove tooltip
    }
}, '.column:not(.disabled)');
```

I had to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` because `hover` isn't a real event, so you can't bind it when delegating.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the parent div has the 'disabled' class like this:

```
if ($(this).parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
    return false;
}
```