# How to choose !(not)$(".some_class")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html menu

```js
$('.mobile-menu_icon').click(function(event) {
  $('.menu-mobile_list').addClass('mobile-menu_active');
});
```

```html
<img src="img/mobile.png" class='pull-right mobile-menu_icon visible-xs' alt="">
  <ul class='menu-mobile_list col-xs-6'>
        <li class="menu-mobile_item"><a href="">Main</a></li>
 <li class="menu-mobile_item"><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
 <li class="menu-mobile_item"><a href="">About Us</a></li>
 <li class="menu-mobile_item"><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
   </ul>
```

How to write something like:

```
!$("ul, li").click(function(e){
   $('.menu-mobile_list').removeClass('mobile-menu_active');
})
```

(if user click on a different place of the screen, but not on menu, menu should close)

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614120/not-class-selector-in-jquery

Comment: To directly answer the question you're asking, there is a [css selector for negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). You can use it like `$('div:not(.some-class)')`

Comment: also [$.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that what you can do is

```
$(body).click(function(e)
{ if(!$(e.target).is( 'ul'))
{
$('.menu-mobile_list').removeClass('mobile-menu_active'); 
}
});
```

Comment: `e.target != 'ul'` will always be `true` because `e.target` is a **DOM element** (which is always a  different value than a *string*).

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to show how this is done.