# jQuery how to select a class with a particular name

Tags: jquery

I have 2 classes `edit-button` and `edit-button hidden`. When I try `$('.edit-button)`, I get

```
(2) [button.btn.btn-gear.edit-button.hidden, button.btn.btn-gear.edit-button, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".edit-button"]
0:button.btn.btn-gear.edit-button.hidden
1:button.btn.btn-gear.edit-button
context:document
length:2
prevObject:jQuery.fn.init(1)
selector:".edit-button"
```

How can I get only the class with `edit-button` and eliminate  the ones with `edit-button hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.edit-button:not(.hidden)')
```

[Not class selector in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614120/not-class-selector-in-jquery)

- corrected

Comment: `$('button.edit-button:not(.hidden)')` would be correct