# body:not(div.class) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery, I made a button to open/close the menu and it's work. But I want to allow the click of anywhere on the body to close the menu. So when we click outside the `.burger` I want to close the menu.

So I made this:

edit : this is my all code for menu

```
var count = 0;
function menu(){
$('.burger').click(function(){
  if (count==0) {
    $('.navigation').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'1'});
    count=1;
  }else{
    $('.navigation').css({'display':'none', 'opacity':'0'});
    count=0;
  }
  });
}
menu();

if(count == 1){
 $("body *:not(.burger)").click(function(event){
$('.navigation').css({'display':'none', 'opacity':'0'});
count=0;
});
}
```

But when I click on .burger, it shows the alert.
 Like this, my menu appear and desappear when i click on .burger, but nothing work when I click outside of .burger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not class selector in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614120/not-class-selector-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting a binding on everything that is not the burger, I would use a delegate event binding that filters out events that bubble up.

```js
$('.burger').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  $('#menu').toggleClass('hide');
});

$(document.body).on('click', ':not(.burger)', function(e){
  $('#menu').addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.burger {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:lightblue;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: gray;
  min-width: 1920px;
  min-height: 1080px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="burger">Burger icon</div>
  <ul id="menu" class="hide">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes thank you very much with e.stopPropagation on click on burger it's work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting all body tags that don't match `div.burger`. This will simply select the body tag (As it doesn't match `div.burger`).

To match all elements in body, that don't have the tag `.burger`, Try this instead:

```
$("body *:not(.burger)").click(function(){alert('ok');
    $('.nav').css({"display":"none"});
});
```

Likewise, if you want to match **ONLY DIVS** that don't have the class `.burger`, use `div:not(.burger)` (You shouldn't even need body here, as a div should not appear outside of the <body> tag):

```js
$("body *:not(.burger)").click(function(){
    alert('matched body *:not(.burger)');
});

$("div:not(.burger)").click(function(){
    alert('matched div:not(.burger)');
});
```

```css
div
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="burger">Burger</div>
<div>Not a burger</div>
```

Comment: Another option is to use jQuery's `.not()`: `$("body *").not("div.burger"))`

Comment: Thanks but no solution works..
The first, make exactly the same thing, when I click on .burger I have the alert
The second work but all my div have width:90% and margin:auto, so when I click around the div, it doesn't work
And with .not(): $("body *").not("div.burger")) it's the same result as the first solution

Comment: @CoraLie You were missing a closing `'` after `$('.nav`. Be sure you've included it in your source. The code in the snippet clearly shows that these selectors work the way you want. You likely have another issue in your souce code, that I can't debug, because you need to post more information.

Comment: Ok this is my all source

  var count = 0;
  function menu(){


    $('.burger').click(function(){
      if (count==0) {
        $('.nav').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'1'});
        count=1;
      }else{
        $('.nav').css({'display':'none', 'opacity':'0'});
        count=0;
      }
      });
}
menu();

if(count == 1){
  $("body *:not(.burger)").click(function(event){
     $('.nav').css({'display':'none', 'opacity':'0'});
        count=0;
  });
} 
Like this, my menu appear and desappear when i click on .burger, but nothing work when I click outside of .burger

Comment: Please edit your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0):

**With function [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) you can accomplish that.**

```js
$(".body *").not("div.burger").click(function(){  
    $('.nav').css({"display":"none"}); 
});
```

```css
.burger {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">

<div class='burger'>
  Burger div (Click and nothing happend)
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="nav">
  
  Click this overlay div to hide it!
</div>
</div>
```

**Hope it helps!**